# Messages not getting picked up from a queue having underscore in its name

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

I have a WCF service `QueuedService.TicketingService.svc` hosted in IIS under application name `QueuedService_1_1`. So the complete URL for the service is:

```
http://example.com/QueuedService_1_1/QueuedService.TicketingService.svc
```

The service is having a net.msmq endpoint :

```
<endpoint address="net.msmq://example.com/private/QueuedService_1_1/QueuedService.TicketingService.svc"
          binding="netMsmqBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingTransactional" 
          contract="QueuedService.ITicketingService" />
```

I have created a queue in MSMQ named:

```
QueuedService_1_1/QueuedService.TicketingService.svc
```

When I call this service, the messages are getting delivered to the queue, but not getting picked up by the service. When I hit the service URL in the browser, the messages get picked by the service.

Is the problem with the naming i.e. `_1_1` in the IIS application name and the queue name? 
Because when I host the same service without `_1_1` i.e. `QueuedService` in IIS and queue named `QueuedService/QueuedService.TicketingService.svc`, it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! You could add the same response as an answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it will work but try `-` instead of `_`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267050(v=bts.10).aspx).